# HSTS over HTTP-CDN-HTTPs chain

Tags: tls, certificates, hsts, cloudflare

I'm using CloudFlare's flexible SSL:

> Flexible SSL: You cannot configure HTTPS support on your origin, even
>   with a certificate that is not valid for your site. Visitors will be
>   able to access your site over HTTPS, but connections to your origin
>   will be made over HTTP. Note: You may encounter a redirect loop with
>   some origin configurations.

The reason I'm using it is simple: I can't afford paid SSL certificate and using Let's Encrypt doesn't seem great, due to the need for an update the certificate each 90 days.

I have several concerns about CloudFlare SSL and the HSTS use with anything that works as CloudFlare's flexible SSL(user-cloudflare with HTTPS, cloudflare-myServer with HTTP). How exactly in cases like this(http-CDN-https) security achieved with HSTS, or is it not?

Any additional explanations and recommendation would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Your excuse for not using HTTPS to your origin at all is based on wrong understanding. You can use your own self-signed certificate, i.e. no need to buy something or use Let's Encrypt. To cite from [their support site](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170416-What-do-the-SSL-options-mean-): *Full SSL: A secure connection between your visitor and Cloudflare, plus a secure connection (__but not authenticated__) between Cloudflare and your web server. You will need to have your server configured to answer HTTPS connections, __with at least a self-signed certificate__."*

Comment: Apart from that your question is not clear. What are exactly the concerns you have and how these are not addressed by the [several questions about this topic on this site](https://www.google.com/search?q=cloudflare+freessl+site%3Asecurity.stackexchange.com). And what has HSTS to do with it (which just means that HTTPS should be used for all future connections to this site)?

Comment: Thanks, @SteffenUllrich, I thought I need dedicated IP for the self-signed certificate(still worry about it, tho). So, if I make my own self-signed certificate, it will be secured connection(encrypted), but it will warn visitors if it's accessed directly(because it's self signed), but CloudFlare will accept it with Full SSL. Correct, right? If so, the end user still will get the warning message. isn't?

Comment: The end user will not get a warning since it will have no contact with your (self-signed) certificate. All what he sees is the publicly trusted certificate created by CloudFlare for your site, not your original self-signed certificate. While FullSSL is not as secure as  Strict FullSSL (where you need a publicly trusted certificate) it is more secure than FreeSSL.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, I really appriciate your help. I've installed self-signed certificate and switched to Full mode with CloudFlare and waiting for it to take effect.

Comment: Note that 90-day renewal is not inconvenient as it can be done automatically without user interaction.

Comment: @multithr3at3d Not only that, but I believe Apache is integrating or has integrated the ACME client (for LetsEncrypt), making automatic renewal even easier.